# How to change the css class="current" when using page jumping (single page website)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Morning,

I must be asking google all the wrong questions, because I can't find anything similar.

I have a standard navigation list, but I'm using **page jumping** because I wanted a single web page.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#livestream">Livestream</a></li>
<li><a href="#media">Media</a></li>
<li><a href="#crew">Crew</a></li>
<li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out **how to make the class="current"** when using page jumping. I've tried [this bit of jquery](http://wiki.shopify.com/How_to_Style_Active_link_%28link_to_current_page%29_with_JavaScript_and_CSS) because it appears to be what I'm looking for, but it did nothing. I don't think it'll work for #links.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you mean `how to make the class="current"`? Do you want to add the class `current` to the clicked link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add the current-class to the `a` that has been clicked, you can accomplish it like this:

```
// Wait for the DOM to be ready
$(function(){
   // Add click-event listener
   $("li a").click(function(){
      // Remove the current class from all a tags
      $("li a").removeClass("current");
      // Add the current class to the clicked a
      $(this).addClass("current");
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Now what does this mean "remove the current class from all a tags"? I don't want to strip the whole page. Would it be correct to add $(".header-navi li a").click(function() ? I've already added it, and it doesn't break anything, but would this be correct?

Comment: Sure, that would work. I just didn't know what the rest of your DOM looked like. Your selector `".header-navi li a"` will select only `a` tags, that are children of an `li`, which in turn have to be children of an element with class `header-navi`. In that case, you should use the same selector for the `$(".header-navi li a").removeClass("current")` as well.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to put the class=current on?

Logic to apply it to A on click and remove form all other links:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  //remove from other links, they're no longer current
  $('a').removeClass('current'); 
  //this is now the current active link.
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

This is what you were asking, I believe. Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

As we are talking about anchors, you should do a `.preventDefault()` to make sure the anchor default action is not fired.

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ubedar/2/edit)*

```
$('ul#nav li:eq(0) a').addClass('current');

$('ul li a').on('click',function(e){ // assign 'e' event
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor action
  
  $('.current').toggleClass();
  $(this).addClass('current');
  
  
  var goToPage = $(this).attr('href'); // get the link href 
  var pagePos = $(goToPage).position().top; 
  $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop: pagePos}, 2000);  
});
```